# Inner Join two tables with aggregate column value

Tags: sql-server, join

Let's say I have two tables: [ReceivingLog] and [Customer_Event]. Please see given tables below.

**Log**

```
     logId    eventId    customerId    pmCount    pmWeight
       1       1411       4196            1         14
       2       1411       4196            2         14
       3       1411       4198            1         14
       4       1411       4198            1         11
       5       1411       4196            3         10
```

**Customer_Event**

```
     customerId    eventId
       4196         1411 
       4198         1411
       4199         1411
```

I'd like to get this kind of result

```
     customerId    pmCount    pmWeight
       4196           6          38 
       4198           2          25 
       4199           0           0
```

I tried this query below, but I get duplicate rows

```
SELECT [Log].customerId, [Log].pmCount, [Log].pmWeight
FROM [Log] INNER JOIN [Customer_Event] ON [Log].eventId = [Customer_Event].eventId
WHERE [Log].eventId = 1411
```

What query should I use to get the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I threw in some sample data and tried it out, works fine:

```
drop table if exists #ReceivingLog, #Customer_Event
go 

create table #ReceivingLog
(
logId       int,
eventId     int,
customerId  int,
pmCount     int,
pmWeight    int
);
go 

insert into #ReceivingLog values 
(1, 1411, 4196, 1, 14)
, (2, 1411, 4196, 2, 14)
, (3, 1411, 4198, 1, 14)
, (4, 1411, 4198, 1, 11)
, (5, 1411, 4196, 3, 10)
go 

create table #Customer_Event
(
customerId  int,
eventId     int
);
go 

insert into #Customer_Event values 
  (4196, 1411)
, (4198, 1411)
, (4199, 1411)
go 

select  c.customerId
        , coalesce(sum(r.pmCount), 0) as SumOfPmCount
        , coalesce(sum(r.pmWeight), 0) as SumOfPmWeight
from    #Customer_Event c
left 
join    #ReceivingLog r
        on c.customerId = r.customerId
            and c.eventid = r.eventid
        and c.eventid = 1411
group 
by      c.customerId
go
```

Comment: but when I add , (6, 1423, 4196, 1, 100) into #ReceivingLog and , (4196, 1423) into #Customer_Event - it counts the pmCount and pmWeight from another eventId as well

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work, untested.

```
Select c.CustomerID, sum(l.pmCount), sum(l.pmWeight)
from Customer_Event c
    left join Log l on c.CustomerID = l.CustomerID and c.eventId = l.eventID
group by c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Select c.CustomerID, ISNULL(sum(l.pmCount),0), ISNULL(sum(l.pmWeight),0)
from #Customer_Event c
    left join #ReceivingLog l on c.eventId = l.eventID and c.customerId = l.customerId
group by c.CustomerID
```

Comment: this also works with the where clause: where c.eventId = 1411